# Help with multiple image jquery hover

Tags: jquery, class, hover

Hey guys, sorry I am new to Jquery. I have always tried to do everyting with CSS but I am trying to cut my code down significantly for a website. 
What I am trying to do, is have it so that when one div.class img is hovered, that it will change the source file of 2 images at the same time.
I can get this to happen, but I need those two images to have different source files.
I am also trying to keep the code simple enough that I can set my image source in the HTML and not have to set every image in the script. The reason for this is the actual application will have several 100 images. Defining the rollover states in CSS and in the script is too bulky and messy.

Here is what I have so far.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
       $(".on img").hover(
            function() {
    $(".on img").attr("src", $(".on img").attr("src").split(".").join("_hover."));
}, 
function() {
    $(".on img").attr("src", $(".on img").attr("src").split("_hover.").join("."));
        });
   });

    </script>
```

So I am using a DIV class to specify any of the images that I want to change, or that will be hovered. 
So any image will have that rollover state, when any other image in that class is hovered.

The problem is right now, that when all the images in that class change, they are all changing to the SAME image source where I need them to change to their own image source. So x.jpg becomes x_hover.jpg and y.jpg becomes y_hover.jpg, etc.

Here is the HTML so for this example.

```
    <div class="on"><img src="api.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="on"><img src="ex.jpg"  /></div>
    <div class="on"><img src="api.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="on"><img src="ex.jpg"  /></div>
```

Thanks!! Anyone that can help, it will be greatly appreciated. I am new to Jquery and I have been searching for days on how to do this.

-JK

Comment: If I hover over the `<img src="api.jpg" />` in the first `div` which other images should change? And what should they change to?

Comment: Never apologise for being new to something :-) It's great you've discovered jQuery, and we all have to start from somewhere!

Comment: @Jam --> jQ it's so amazing that I'd like to go back in the past 5 month and start again! :)

Comment: Ha ha same! I've got an old project that should have had it, but I had never heard of jQuery! Such a shame :-( - it took ages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I could come up with for this, to change the `src` of the hovered-over element is:

```
$('.on img').hover(
    function(){
        var cur = this.src.split('.');
        var extension = cur.pop();
        this.src = cur.join('.') + '_hover.' + extension;
    },
    function(){
        this.src = this.src.replace('_hover','');
    }
);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vVxCQ/1/).

---

**Edited** in response to question, in comments to this answer, from @Jamie:

> Do you know how I can make this apply to ALL images that are in that div class, but have each image change to it's own image? For example: a.jpg to change to a_hover.jpg, then back to a.jpg while b.jpg changes to b_hover.jpg, then revert back to b.jpg. I want all of these image to change at the same time, if the cursor is hovering an image in that div class.

The following jQuery script will take care of that for you:

```
$('.on img').hover(
    function(){
        $('.on img').each(
            function(){
                var cur = this.src.split('.');
                var extension = cur.pop();
                this.src = cur.join('.') + '_hover.' + extension;
            });
    },
    function(){
        $('.on img').each(
            function(){
                this.src = this.src.replace('_hover','');
            });
    }

);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vVxCQ/2/).

**Edited** to fix the above URL, which, for some reason, was to an image rather than the demo. Silly me...it *now* links to the actual demo. Sorry.

Comment: @roXon: the `pop()` just takes the last element from the array (`cur`) and assigns it to the `extension` variable. And thank you :)

Comment: Arrrrgh I took some time to finally see that .pop is the good old javascript  method! haha The good old JS ;) great!

Comment: Hey David, I like your coding, it is nice and clean!
Do you know how I can make this apply to ALL images that are in that div class, but have each image change to it's own image?

For example: a.jpg to change to a_hover.jpg, then back to a.jpg while b.jpg changes to b_hover.jpg, then revert back to b.jpg. I want all of these image to change at the same time, if the cursor is hovering an image in that div class. I hope this makes sense, sorry I suck at explaining things sometimes. 
I am hoping you can help me. I am up against a brick wall here.

Thank you ver much!!!

Comment: David you are my hero! 
It makes total sense now that I see it but I have spent forever on this! This was my first jquery script so I can't thank you enough for helping me out!

Comment: @Jamie, excellent! I can now, *legitimately*, wear my underwear on the outside! =D Also, less revealingly, I'm glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 1):

Just my take with regex

```
$('.on img').hover(function() {
  this.src = this.src.replace(/(.*)(\.[^.]+)$/, '$1_hover$2');
}, function() {
  this.src = this.src.replace(/_hover(\.[^.]+)$/, '$1');
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/nWc2D/

Comment: +1 @Gary (if you have some time) is there some good tut that you'd like to suggest for Regular Expressions? (thanks in advance!)

Comment: You know what, I can't even remember how I began to learn regex. It just happened. :D The best thing to do is just practise matching strings using tools such as Regex Buddy or online tools, I like http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ -- start off with the basics -- http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html -- it gets hard when you start learning about greedyness, lookbehinds, lookarounds, etc, but keep practising and you'll get there!

Comment: Nice, thanks! I will surely!! Your example seem just like you said: looks like "Once you get it: you have it!" I'm sure it's fun to work with minimalistic 'signs'. Like building a boat in a bottle! :) all the splits, joins, ifs, afters, befores, arrays... fun fun fun

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".on img").hover(
            function() {
                   $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").split(".").join("_hover."));
            } , 
            function() {
                   $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").split("_hover.").join("."));
           });
   });
```

In this context `$(this)` will give you the hovered image rather than all images with that class.

Comment: Sorry guys, I think I wasn't very good at explaining. I can get each image to rollover individually. I was using $(this) before.

What I am trying to do is to get ALL the images in that class to change when one is hovered.
AND 
Have each image be different from the others.